# How to rearrange a radioactive decay equation y = mx +c

Tags: exponential-function

I have the equation $\frac{dN}{dt}= - Nk$ where $k$ is the decay constant.

When $time = 0$,

we get  $N(t) = N(0)  e^{-kt}$.

How would I rearrange this to the $y = mx + c$ format? How would I find the decay constant?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transform the equation into a linear equation, but then you have to take logs of $N(t)$ and $N(0)$

$\ln(N(t))=\ln \left[(N(0))\cdot e^{k\cdot t}\right]$

$\ln(N(t))=\ln (N(0))+\ln\left[ e^{k\cdot t}\right]$

$\ln(N(t))=\ln (N(0))+k\cdot t$

This is equivalent to $y=c+mx$

Let´s say the origin values are

```
t      0  1  2  3  4

N(t)  16  8  4  2  1
```

Now you calculate the logs of $N(t)$. The values of $t$ musn´t be transformed. Two value pairs are sufficient to evaluate the value of $k$.

**Remark**

I have $+k$ at the function, not $-k$. But it doesn´t matter. If you have a decay then the value of k is negative.

Comment: I was wondering how you gained those values of t and N(t)?

Comment: @Matt It´s just the function $N(t)=16\cdot 0.5^t$ .  This is equal to $N(t)=16\cdot e^{\ln(0.5)\cdot t}$, where $N(0)=16$ and $k=\ln(0.5)=-0.693147...$

Comment: I do not think that value of k is right because I am working through these questions on a site (I am a GCSE student attempting to teach myself some A level) and it marked that answer of k as wrong.

Comment: @Matt Please post the question. Without out it I can´t say something if I´m wrong or not.

Comment: It is the exact same except N(t)=N(0)e^(-kt). The N(0) is actually N (little zero done in the style of of chemistry e.g. O2 as in oxygen molecules) I do not know how to actually make it little though.

Comment: @Matt I had a second, third... look on you question. Isnt´t that simple that you have to calculate k from N(t)=N(0)e^(-kt). Since you have the value of N(0) you need one data point to calculate the value of k. Was it your idea with the linear function y = mx + c ? Another thing: I would appreciate it if you would post all information you have-but not in the comments. Make an edit of the quesstion for that purpose. Your thoughts and your work are very, very, very welcomed, but  seperate it from the question.

Comment: The question asked for y = mx + c and then the next question asked for the decay constant

Comment: @matt The decay constant can be calculated by using the equation $N(t)=N(0)e^{-kt}$. Insert the given values and solve for k. To get the form y = mx + c see my answer.

Comment: The values you gave? Because the question did not give any?

Comment: @Matt If you have no values, no function no other information then you must solve the equation $\ln(N(t))=\ln (N(0))+k\cdot t$ in general for $k$.